# How can I tilt a mesh like this?

Tags: modeling

Consider:

[image: Tilt object]

How can I tilt a mesh like that? I have the mesh tilted, but I need to restore it so that it can be straight.

Comment: Hello :). There's a *Shear Tool* specifically for that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a (Shift-Ctrl-Alt S) Shear. It defaults to operating in the View orientation, but that can be changed in its F9 panel.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the *Snap > Vertex* option:

[image]

Then select the top 2 vertices, move along the axis (here X), keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap and snap to the bottom vertex:

[image]